# Memory usage in JavaScript/browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

This will be a bit strange question, but..

I am planning to use jQuery/knockout to write a dynamic custom wizard 
which will depending on different scenarios will load different templates/UI logic to the user.

Question.
Should I take into consideration memory usage in this case? or should I manually unload/clean up/save to the server pieces of UI which is not in use??

PS. Current version of wizard will have 5-7 steps.

Comment: Just write it and stop worrying about micro-managing memory. Especially for such a small wizard. The browser/JS engine should be able to clean up fine.

Comment: What about data? if I keep objects with some fields containing large amount of data? I do understand what this could be original design flow.

Comment: You should ask yourself why you are keeping the data.  Why do you need it later? Can you do your analysis of the data earlier in the flow to keep from needing to store it for a period of time longer than is necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write your app the best you can functionally and then determine if memory is even an issue.  If it is, then you can take steps to reduce it's memory footprint but odds are you'll be fine.  For instance, go look at what a site like Facebook's memory usage, a site that everyone and their grandmother uses.